# Does this optimization algorithm have a name?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, algorithms, numerical-optimization

Let $a<x<y<b$, and suppose that the continuous function $f$ is unimodal (has one weak local maximum) on $[a, b]$. If $f(x) \geq f(y)$, then for any $z \in (y,b]$, we must have $f(y)>f(z)$, or else $f$ would have distinct local maxima on either side of $y$. Therefore $f$ must be maximized on the interval $[a, y]$. Likewise, if $f(y) < f(x)$, then $f$ is maximized on $[x, b]$.

This lends itself to a derivative-free, linearly convergent optimization algorithm. Suppose we wish to maximize $f$ over the interval $[a, b]$. If we pick any $x<y$ on $(a, b)$, after evaluating $f(x)$ and $f(y)$, we can use the above to confine our interest to either $[a, y]$ or $[x, b]$. Continuing recursively, we get a decreasing, nested sequence of intervals on which $f$ is maximized. If we always choose $x=2a/3 + b/3$ and $y=a/3+2b/3$, then we can guarantee that each interval is $2/3$ the length of its successor. Hence the midpoints of the intervals converge linearly to the maximizer of $f$ with rate $2/3$.

This algorithm reminds me of the bisection method for root finding. Does it have a name?

Comment: The optimised version is the [golden-section search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden-section_search), which you get $\frac12(\sqrt5-1)=0.618\dots$ (or in rare occasion $f(x)=f(y)$ square that) instead of $\frac23$ and guarantee reuse of the test points.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: Another interpretation of what I wrote is describing ternary search, which seems to allow rates of convergence nearing 1/2 when $x\approx y$. Although in 64-bit precision, golden-section's reduced cost per iteration might make it more efficient usually. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search

Comment: You could also use quadratic interpolation to find the next guess for the maximum. That would be close to the regula falsi root finder with all its problems, so one has to insert bisection steps (to get an approximate trisection) if the new guess is too close to one of the existing points. This would have its analogous root-finder in the Dekker method.